# Creating database and tables with PK and FK

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

In need of help, I have to build a new database with specific tables with primary keys and foreign keys. I also have an insert Microsoft SQL Server Query File (.sql) that looks like this:

```
print('Insertion des données dans la table Candidats ....')
go
insert into Candidats values (1,10,1)
.......
insert into Candidats values (30,40,1)
go

print ('Insertion des données dans la table Partis ....')
go
insert into Partis values('Parti Liberal', 3000)
.......
insert into Partis values('Independant',100)
go

print('Insertion des données dans la table Resultats ....')
go
insert into Resultats values (1,1,500)
.......
insert into Resultats values (30,1,25)
go

print('Insertion des données dans la table Circonscriptions ....')
go
insert into Circonscriptions values ('Montreal', 3000, 4)
.......
insert into Circonscriptions values ('sabloVille', 1,null)
go

print('Insertion des données dans la table Electeurs ....')
go
insert into Electeurs values ('Paolo Lebeau', '38 Ste-catherine', 100)
.......
insert into Electeurs values ('Bob Lavigne', '4 Stuplate',400)
go
```

With that, I am require to create the database and the tables.

I just don't know where to start.

I tried, directly in SQL SERVER 2008 to create the database, then the tables and I created the columns with the titles and NULL conditions.

After, I ran the .sql file, came back with an error on each print commande.

Then I tried to assign the primary keys and foreign keys, didn't work, then i deleted the PK and when i ran the .sql file, everything worked for insertion but, I had no PK and was unable to add them.

I guess i'm off on something, I would need the procedure step by step... Do I start working on the .sql file or the DB on SQL ??? I'm in need of help please......

Answer (score 0):

Work through this table by table. Build one complete table with all constraints, and see if you can add all of its rows. If yes, try the next table; if no, debug the error messages for the table until it works in isolation.

When each table works in isolation, start combining them, first in the order given in the original SQL file. Since there are PK-FK relationships, it is likely that only one of the possible 120 different orders works. To the extent that you can read the dependencies form the PK-FK relationships, this will eliminate impossible order.

Call back here with specific error situations that arise, which are much more tractable for this community than " It's broken, please help" types of questions.

This process is called **Debugging** and is an integral part of every programmers job. TO the extent that you both get better at it, and better at avoiding it by looking further ahead, you become a more senior developer; but this comes only from the experience of performing the task repeatedly.

Archimedes to Alexander: "There is no royal road to knowledge your highness."

Comment: Insertion des données dans la table Candidats ....
Msg 547, Level 16, State 0, Line 1 The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_Candidats_Partis". The conflict occurred in database "Elections", table "dbo.Partis", column 'no_parti'.
The statement has been terminated.

Comment: Sorry, it says Insertion of data in Candidats table ...Msg 547, Level 16, State 0, Line 1 The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_Candidats_Partis". The conflict occurred in database "Elections", table "dbo.Partis", column 'no_parti'. The statement has been terminated.